# How connect with Git repository over ssh behind evil proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, git, putty

My proxy (192.168.1.1:3128) not allow connection over ssh and I wish work with git repository like this:

for clone:

git clone ssh://user@server.com:2222/~/repository.git

For cheat web forbidden, I use [your-freedom](http://your-freedom.net/) and for connect ssh with a remote server, with your-freedom and putty(allow proxy connection). But clone over ssh I can't, someone can help me?

Grettings.

Comment: Can you clone over http/https? Unless your proxy allows ssh connections, you may be out of luck.

Comment: @Ohnana I can't, only over ssh like this: git clone ssh://user@server.com:2222/~/repository.git